# Best way to host web content in a browser

Tags: browser, tabs, cross-site

Simple example: right-clicking on any link gives the option of 'open in new tab'.

Now instead of the target link taking over the new tab, I'm trying to first impose an immutable header section in the new tab, with the target link's content appearing below the header.

The target link's content can be from any source, so my question is, is there a safe way to accomplish this setup, while preventing the target link's content from being able to modify/suppress my imposed header?

Should I use frames?  Any other approaches?

Comment: Sites can (and often do) refuse to allow themselves to be hosted in frames, see https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html.  E.g. this very page sets `content-security-policy upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com` and `x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN`.

Comment: Thanks @dbc.  I'm fine with that, but for sites that are indifferent, I'm seeking a solution